# How can I get a list of all mounted filesystems in Java on Unix?

Tags: java, unix, filesystems

I'm running Java on a Unix platform. How can I get a list of all mounted filesystems via the Java 1.6 API?

I've tried `File.listRoots()` but that returns a single filesystem (that is, `/`). If I use `df -h` I see more than that:

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   931Gi  843Gi   87Gi    91% 221142498  22838244   91%   /
devfs          187Ki  187Ki    0Bi   100%       646         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%         0         0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s2   1.8Ti  926Gi  937Gi    50% 242689949 245596503   50%   /Volumes/MyBook
/dev/disk2     1.0Gi  125Mi  875Mi    13%     32014    223984   13%   /Volumes/Google Earth
```

I would expect to see `/home` as well (at a minimum).

Comment: /home is there right in the middle, would only show up if /home is mounted from another device though, obviously..

Comment: I know it is. But `File.listRoots()` doesn't return `/home`. That's the point.

Comment: Is it supposed to? `/` is the only true *root* of a unix filesystem. Maybe it is better if you say what you are doing with this function?

Comment: I understand that, but the list of _mounted filesystems_ is different to the filesystem namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java doesn't provide any access to mount points. You have to run system command `mount` via `Runtime.exec()` and parse its output. Either that, or parse the contents of `/etc/mtab`.

Comment: There's no `/etc/mtab` on my Mac OS X machine (Mountain Lion), but there is on my Ubuntu server.

Comment: OS X differs substantially from the "real" Unixes in many respects, so any OS-specific things such as this will likely have to be done differently for it. In any event, `mount` seems like a common tool that should work for Macs as well. I used `df` for similar task, which also works.

Comment: On OS X you can parse the contents of /Volumes using `(new File("/Volumes")).listFiles()`.   One of the entries there is a symbolic link to `/` that you can test with `getCanonicalPath()`.  You'll also have to test for and exclude files that aren't mount points, like the pesky `.DS_Store`.

Comment: For java7+ take a look at [Erik Martino answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26650362/3870761)

Answer (score 18):

In Java7+ you can use nio

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileStore;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;

public class ListMountedVolumesWithNio {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      for (FileStore store : FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
         long total = store.getTotalSpace() / 1024;
         long used = (store.getTotalSpace() - store.getUnallocatedSpace()) / 1024;
         long avail = store.getUsableSpace() / 1024;
         System.out.format("%-20s %12d %12d %12d%n", store, total, used, avail);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a great option!  Unfortunately, there's no easy way to get from the FileStore to the Path/File.  Parsing the toString() is a hackish workaround that may break...

Answer (score 4):

You can try use follow method for resolve issue:

**My code**

```
public List<String> getHDDPartitions() {
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/proc/mounts"), "UTF-8"));
        String response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((response = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(response.replaceAll(" +", "\t") + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return Lists.newArrayList(Arrays.asList(stringBuilder.toString().split("\n")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("{}", ExceptionWriter.INSTANCE.getStackTrace(e));
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Map<String, String>> getMapMounts() {
    List<Map<String, String>> resultList = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (String mountPoint : getHDDPartitions()) {
        Map<String, String> result = Maps.newHashMap();
        String[] mount = mountPoint.split("\t");
        result.put("FileSystem", mount[2]);
        result.put("MountPoint", mount[1]);
        result.put("Permissions", mount[3]);
        result.put("User", mount[4]);
        result.put("Group", mount[5]);
        result.put("Total", String.valueOf(new File(mount[1]).getTotalSpace()));
        result.put("Free", String.valueOf(new File(mount[1]).getFreeSpace()));
        result.put("Used", String.valueOf(new File(mount[1]).getTotalSpace() - new File(mount[1]).getFreeSpace()));
        result.put("Free Percent", String.valueOf(getFreeSpacePercent(new File(mount[1]).getTotalSpace(), new File(mount[1]).getFreeSpace())));
        resultList.add(result);
    }
    return resultList;
}

private Integer getFreeSpacePercent(long total, long free) {
    Double result = (Double.longBitsToDouble(free) / Double.longBitsToDouble(total)) * 100;
    return result.intValue();
}
```

Comment: This does the job well.  I don't know why you don't have more up votes.  Good job!

Answer (score 4):

OSHI (Operating System and Hardware Information library for Java) can be useful here: https://github.com/oshi/oshi.

Check out this code:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    final SystemInfo systemInfo = new SystemInfo();
    final OSFileStore[] fileStores = systemInfo.getOperatingSystem().getFileSystem().getFileStores();
    Stream.of(fileStores)
    .peek(fs ->{
        System.out.println("name: "+fs.getName());
        System.out.println("type: "+fs.getType() );
        System.out.println("str: "+fs.toString() );
        System.out.println("mount: "+fs.getMount());
        System.out.println("...");
    }).count();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the getmntent function (use "man getmntent" to get more information) using JNA.

Here is some example code to get you started:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class MntPointTest {
    public static class mntent extends Structure {
        public String mnt_fsname; //Device or server for filesystem
        public String mnt_dir; //Directory mounted on
        public String mnt_type; //Type of filesystem: ufs, nfs, etc.
        public String mnt_opts;
        public int mnt_freq;
        public int mnt_passno;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("mnt_fsname", "mnt_dir", "mnt_type", "mnt_opts", "mnt_freq", "mnt_passno");
        }
    }

    public interface CLib extends Library {
        CLib INSTANCE = (CLib) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLib.class);

        Pointer setmntent(String file, String mode);
        mntent getmntent(Pointer stream);
        int endmntent(Pointer stream);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mntent mntEnt;
        Pointer stream = CLib.INSTANCE.setmntent("/etc/mtab", "r");
        while ((mntEnt = CLib.INSTANCE.getmntent(stream)) != null) {
            System.out.println("Mounted from: " + mntEnt.mnt_fsname);
            System.out.println("Mounted on: " + mntEnt.mnt_dir);
            System.out.println("File system type: " + mntEnt.mnt_type);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        }

        CLib.INSTANCE.endmntent(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this great answer! do you perhaps know if there is a project or library that maps all common methods to java (i mean like mount/umount and friends)?

Comment: I'm working on a project at https://github.com/dblock/oshi that does this sort of JNA-based mapping of key operating system native code (memory, files, cpu, battery, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I was already on the way to using `mount` when @Cozzamara pointed out that's the way to go. What I ended up with is:

```
    // get the list of mounted filesystems
    // Note: this is Unix specific, as it requires the "mount" command
    Process mountProcess = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ( "mount" );
    BufferedReader mountOutput = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( mountProcess.getInputStream () ) );
    List<File> roots = new ArrayList<File> ();
    while ( true ) {

        // fetch the next line of output from the "mount" command
        String line = mountOutput.readLine ();
        if ( line == null )
            break;

        // the line will be formatted as "... on <filesystem> (...)"; get the substring we need
        int indexStart = line.indexOf ( " on /" );
        int indexEnd = line.indexOf ( " ", indexStart );
        roots.add ( new File ( line.substring ( indexStart + 4, indexEnd - 1 ) ) );
    }
    mountOutput.close ();
```

Comment: Should this line: `roots.add ( new File ( line.substring ( indexStart + 4, indexEnd - 1 ) ) );` be: `roots.add ( new File ( line.substring ( indexStart + 4, indexEnd) ) );`?