# Network File System properties through JAVA?

Tags: java

I have to read nfs mounts from the system and need to calculate its total space and free space.
I need to use only JAVA.
Can someone please help regarding this.

Comment: So what have you tried. Can you run mount -a and extract the nfs mounts?

Comment: Did you check whether the [java.nio.file.FileStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html) methods return the correct values for your NFS volume? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430825/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-mounted-filesystems-in-java-on-unix. And, btw, you should probably go through [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I wanted to know if any Java API provides the required functionality.