# Find root directory for a given file on Linux using Java

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

I'm trying to implement a trash support on Linux according to [specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html). It states

> It MAY also choose to provide trashing in the “top directories” of some or all mounted resources. This trashing is done in two ways, described below as (1) and (2).
>
> (1) An administrator can create an $topdir/.Trash directory. The permissions on this directories should permit all users who can trash files at all to write in it.; and the “sticky bit” in the permissions must be set, if the file system supports it.
>
> When trashing a file from a non-home partition/device4 , an implementation (if it supports trashing in top directories) MUST check for the presence of $topdir/.Trash.

If I understand it correctly, I will need to find the `$topdir` which, according to my understanding, is the root of the mounted file system/partition.

Using

```
FileStore store = FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores();
```

I can get all `FileStore` that seem to be the mount-points, but I don't see a **reliable** way to get the mount-point as `File`, `Path` or String.

How to find out the mount-points from (plain) Java?

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided, this is the exact description of `$topdir`

> Top directory , $topdir — the directory where a file system is mounted. “/” is the top directory for the root file system, but not for the other mounted file systems. For example, separate file systems might be mounted on “/home”, “/media/flash”, etc. In this text, the designation “$topdir” is used for “any top directory”.

The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430825/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-mounted-filesystems-in-java-on-unix) suggest ways to get the mount information although I think it is rather roundabout. Hope this helps!